# can we theme back-end add post form for custom post type in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I need to theme add/edit post form in WordPress backend. I need to apply my custom css and div/html for add/edit post page.
For reference Please check Screenshot of the page I want to theme.
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3866944/3aaacca17ca827fe7dca1d4e17de96ce

If you have any idea or suggestions will be helpful for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your screenshot is simply the new Gutenberg Editor that comes with Wordpress >5.0
Changing the CSS shouldn't be a big problem. Changing the whole behaviour, i dont know. very broad question.
https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+backend+design&oq=wordpress+backend+design&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j69i64l2.4887j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Beatroot screenshot only represent backend form for add/edit post. I need to theme add/edit post form for my custom post type. I did n't get any suitable solution for that. Admin theme only override css for changing layout. Is there any way we can theme whole form or use template for add/edit post form.

Comment: @Beatroot  I have changed screenshot to show my custom post type.

Comment: you can use hooks for styles and scripts loading in the backend. then check for the post_type in the querystring. that why you only style your own post_type. this may be of help
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3143/adding-css-to-custom-post-type-admin-page-causes-error